# How to reuse postgresql RETURNING id in PHP for INPUT field as hidden value

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I get the last id from Postgresql pdo input sql statement, just in case there are more than one user for `INPUT` into same table, I did not use the `lastval()` or `currval()`. I would want my `INSERT` statement's id (auto increment) stored in HTML hidden input value, so the value can be reuse in other form for id consistency.

My problem is how to get the Postgres returning value into HTML hidden input text field

```
$Id2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name(a,b,c)VALUES('$a','$b','$c')
RETURNING id    
");

$Id2_status = $Id2->execute();
```

How to grab the last id from the returning id value into this input text value?

```
<input type ='hidden' name='lastid' value='".$lastid."' >";
```

Comment: Improved code highlighting for code blocks and code expressions inside regular text.

Comment: Use ajax to insert data and return id .Then set that id in hidden by jquery

Comment: You need to use placeholders in the query.